# JavaScript: show and hide divs from a list of items working just once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, click

I have a list of links. When I click on them a sub layer shows, when I click back again this sub layer hides.

```
**HTML:**

    <!-- list of links-->
<div id="results">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="showMore" id="1">Click to show more information about 1</a><br>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="showMore" id="2">Click to show more information about 2</a><br>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="showMore" id="3">Click to show more information about 3</a><br>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="showMore" id="4">Click to show more information about 4</a><br>
    <!-- sub layers for each of the links -->
    <div class="1">about 1<br>
        <a onclick="javascript:saveItem('1'); return false;" href="javascript:return false;">Record info about 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="2">about 2<br>
        <a onclick="javascript:saveItem('2'); return false;" href="javascript:return false;">Record info about 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="3">about 3<br>
        <a onclick="javascript:saveItem('3'); return false;" href="javascript:return false;">Record info about 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="4">about 4<br>
        <a onclick="javascript:saveItem('4'); return false;" href="javascript:return false;">Record info about 4</a>
    </div>

</div>

**JS:**


    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $(".showMore").click(function(e){
            $("." + e.currentTarget.id).toggle()
        });
    }); 

    function saveItem(id)
    {
        $.blockUI({ message: 'Loading ...'});
        theUrl = 'controller.php';

        $.ajax ({
            url: laUrl,
            data: params,
            type: "POST",
            async:true,
            success: function (data, textStatus)
            {   
                $('#results').html (data); 
                $.unblockUI();                  
            }
        }); 
    }
```

It's working great. But when I click  on the link inside of the sub layer, the link with the `saveItem` function, the function saves the link, reloads the results `div` and the show and hide layers won't work anymore.

No errors, just not working.

How do I rebind the showMore click ?? or how do I re-add the handlers? Sorry, I'm not quite fluent in javascript/jquery

Any ideas?

Thanks !!

EDIT: I've found the solution.

I just had to add:

```
  $(".showMore").click(function(e){
            $("." + e.currentTarget.id).toggle()
        });
```

after:

```
$.unblockUI();
```

in the saveItem function.

That easy ^_^

Comment: a fiddle would be much more helpful to figure out the prob?

Comment: Seems you're setting event handlers in onload on the items, but when reloading them you remove the items with handlers and add new ones without. You never re-add the handlers.

Comment: I take it all those links are within the results container?  if so you will need to rebind the showMore click

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors Class names cannot start with a digit and must be 2 characters or longer. Try changing the ids to be something like `"show-more-{\d}"` and just get the corresponding div with `$('show-more-' + index)`

Comment: How do I rebind the showMore click ?? or how do I re-add the handlers? Sorry, I'm not quite fluent in javascript/jquery :(

Comment: Try adding `$(".showMore").trigger("click");` at the end of `function saveItem`..  [About Trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: Thanks   Bhavik, but not working :((